# Why is the gazebo ubuntu package available both at packages.osrfoundation.org and packages.ros.org?

Tags: installation

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

The current installation instructions for gazebo state that one should only use the information on gazebosim.org, which points to the repository at "http://packages.osrfoundation.org/gazebo/ubuntu".  However, the standalone version of gazebo also seems to be available at "http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu" (at least for precise).

Given all the recent changes regarding the gazebo website, installation instructions, ROS integration, etc. (and the inevitably resulting confusion), wouldn't it be better to just have gazebo in the osrfoundation.org repository?

This would avoid confusion due to different versions being available in the different repositories, and it would also make it clear that gazebo is really a standalone project, which can be integrated with ROS with help from packages from the gazebo_ros_pkgs ROS meta-package.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/4404/why-is-the-gazebo-ubuntu-package-available-both-at-packages.osrfoundation.org-and-packages.ros.org?/) by [leblanc_kevin](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/496/leblanc_kevin/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 15 on 2013-09-20

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

ROS used to pull Gazebo into its eco-system. ROS Groovy marked the end of that behavior. To properly tick-tock this change we released Gazebo 1.9 into ROS Groovy in order to give people time to switch.

---

Originally posted by [nkoenig](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/5/nkoenig/) with karma: 7676 on 2013-09-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [leblanc_kevin](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/496/leblanc_kevin/) on 2013-10-09**:
Thanks for the clarification.